# "TLS support is not available" when creating GTlsClientConnection with libnice

Tags: ssl, tcp, glib, libnice

I have working code where two peers are connecting over a relay server (coturn) and everything seems to be fine over pseudo-tcp. I've tested message exchange successfully with `nice_agent_attach_recv()` and `nice_agent_get_io_stream()`.

But when I try to create a `GTlsClientConnection` I get back: `0:TLS support is not available`

Here is some partial code:

```
   if(!nice_agent_set_relay_info(agent, stream_id, 
       NICE_COMPONENT_TYPE_RTP, 
       "my.coturn.server", 
       5349, //tls-listener-port (I also tried the non tls port: 3478)
       username.c_str(), 
       password.c_str(), 
       NICE_RELAY_TYPE_TURN_TCP)) 
   {
        printf("error setting up relay info\n");
   }

   ...

   //after state has changed to NICE_COMPONENT_STATE_READY

   ...

   io_stream = nice_agent_get_io_stream (agent, stream_id, component_id);
   input = g_io_stream_get_input_stream (G_IO_STREAM (io_stream));
   output = g_io_stream_get_output_stream (G_IO_STREAM (io_stream));

   GIOStream* tlsConnection  = g_tls_client_connection_new 
                               (G_IO_STREAM (io_stream), NULL, &error);

   /////////////////////////
   /// error == 0 (TLS support is not available)
```

I am new to libnice and glib. So, I may be missing something basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably need the `glib-networking` package installed.

Comment: interesting. So, it would still compile and link but fail at creating a TLS support? I'll give it a try.

Comment: The Tls classes in Gio just rely on a generic interface but it doesn't contain any implementation. glib-networking provides an implementation that depends on external TLS libraries.

Comment: that did it. Now I just have to get all the cert and streams going. But got me past my very beginner problem. thanks!

Comment: glib-networking is already the newest version (2.48.2-1~ubuntu16.04.1).
I have the above package and still I get the same problem